# CSS - Setting minimum and maximum width

Tags: html, css

Instead of defining a fixed width of a div, I want to specify a minimum width (if the content is very less), and a maximum width (if the content is more, hide the extra content).

For example, my html is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="test">x</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
    padding:10px; 
    border:1px solid red; 
    width:200px; 
    text-align:center;
}

.test{
    border:1px solid green; 
}
```

As you can see, the container has the fixed width of 200px. I want to place the test div in the center of container. Since there is only a single letter in the test class, so I want that the test class should be minimum 50px, but maximum 100px.

I've tried min-width and max-width, but couldn't make it work. Here is the [jsfiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/SnhhK/)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

By using the `margin:0 auto;` you can get it centralised :) (Just remove it if you dont want it centered)

http://jsfiddle.net/SnhhK/4/

Comment: Thanks, but min-width does not really work in the example. I want to do that if the content inside the test is very less like 1 character, then the minimum width should be 50px. if the content is more and does not fit, then the width of test div should increase but should not be more than 100px. Hope you get my point.

Comment: OK, well if thats the case (if i understand correctly :P) then you dont need the min-width, just set the width, and then display:block. Ive updated this example http://jsfiddle.net/SnhhK/5/

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `<div>` are block level elements which do not auto-resize to fit their content. What you can do is, make your div behave like `table-cell` which do have resizing ability and set `min-width` and `max-width` to it.

```
.test {
min-width: 200px;
max-width:1000px;
display: table-cell;
word-wrap: break-word;
word-break: break-all;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using min and max-width on the ,test element worked for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/SnhhK/1/